# Running py.test displays repeated unicode

Tags: python, pytest

The project running `py.test` handles calls to the `Twilio` API. Running `py.test` on a directory or a particular test file returns the test results, but also a sequence of repeated unicode characters. This happens for both successful and failed tests.

Could this be due to an improper installation of `py.test` or perhaps conflicts with plugins?

[image: pytest run]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the script is trying to use [ANSI escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) to display different colours etc. However, these seem to be getting interpreted as [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8).

My recommendation would be to check your terminal settings.